# Message is being sent with "send_message" in ejabberd using postman but not received by client

Tags: postman, xmpp, ejabberd, ejabberd-api

I have configured and install ejabberd on the **ubuntu 22.04** and I have successfully configured and create one user with administrator right and as well as create some users into it.

**I am using Version**

- ***OS - ubuntu 22.04 LTS***
- ***ejabberd 22.10***

And also configured ejabberd API by **mod_http_api** and then I test APIs with POSTMAN, almost every ([link](https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/ejabberd-api/admin-api/)) "**API reference**" working fine with it except **send_message**.

Here is my ejabberd.yml configuration:-

```yaml
hosts:
  - B660M-D2H-DDR4
  - localhost
  - XX.XXX.37.XX

loglevel: info

ca_file: /opt/ejabberd/conf/cacert.pem

certfiles:
  - /opt/ejabberd/conf/server.pem

## If you already have certificates, list them here
# certfiles:
#  - /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/fullchain.pem
#  - /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/privkey.pem

listen:
  -
    port: 5222
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_c2s
    max_stanza_size: 262144
    shaper: c2s_shaper
    access: c2s
    starttls_required: true
  -
    port: 5223
    ip: "::"
    tls: true
    module: ejabberd_c2s
    max_stanza_size: 262144
    shaper: c2s_shaper
    access: c2s
    starttls_required: true
  -
    port: 5269
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_s2s_in
    max_stanza_size: 524288
  -
    port: 5443
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_http
    tls: true
    request_handlers:
      /admin: ejabberd_web_admin
      /api: mod_http_api
      /bosh: mod_bosh
      /captcha: ejabberd_captcha
      /upload: mod_http_upload
      /ws: ejabberd_http_ws
  -
    port: 5280
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_http
    request_handlers:
      /admin: ejabberd_web_admin
      /.well-known/acme-challenge: ejabberd_acme    
      /api: mod_http_api
  -
    port: 3478
    ip: "::"
    transport: udp
    module: ejabberd_stun
    use_turn: true
    ## The server's public IPv4 address:
    # turn_ipv4_address: "203.0.113.3"
    ## The server's public IPv6 address:
    # turn_ipv6_address: "2001:db8::3"
  -
    port: 1883
    ip: "::"
    module: mod_mqtt
    backlog: 1000
  
s2s_use_starttls: optional

acl:
  admin: 
    user: "admin@localhost"
  local:
    user_regexp: ""
  loopback:
    ip:
      - 127.0.0.0/8
      - ::1/128

access_rules:
  local:
    allow: local
    allow: XX.XXX.37.XX
  c2s:
    deny: blocked
    allow: all
  announce:
    allow: admin
  configure:
    allow: admin
  muc_create:
    allow: local
  pubsub_createnode:
    allow: local
  trusted_network:
    allow: loopback

api_permissions:
  "console commands":
    from:
      - ejabberd_ctl
    who: all
    what: "*"
  "admin access":
    who:
      access:
        allow:
          - acl: admin
      oauth:
        scope: "ejabberd:admin"
        access:
          allow:
            - acl: admin
    what:
      - "*"
      - "!stop"
      - "!start"
  "public commands":
    who:
      ip: 127.0.0.1/8
    what:
      - status
      - connected_users_number

shaper:
  normal:
    rate: 3000
    burst_size: 20000
  fast: 100000

shaper_rules:
  max_user_sessions: 10
  max_user_offline_messages:
    5000: admin
    100: all
  c2s_shaper:
    none: admin
    normal: all
  s2s_shaper: fast

modules:
  mod_adhoc: {}
  mod_admin_extra: {}
  mod_announce:
    access: announce
  mod_avatar: {}
  mod_blocking: {}
  mod_bosh: {}
  mod_caps: {}
  mod_carboncopy: {}
  mod_client_state: {}
  mod_configure: {}
  mod_disco: {}
  mod_fail2ban: {}
  mod_http_api: {}
  mod_http_upload:
    put_url: https://@HOST@:5443/upload
    custom_headers:
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "https://@HOST@"
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,HEAD,PUT,OPTIONS"
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type"
  mod_last: {}
  mod_mam:
    ## Mnesia is limited to 2GB, better to use an SQL backend
    ## For small servers SQLite is a good fit and is very easy
    ## to configure. Uncomment this when you have SQL configured:
    ## db_type: sql
    assume_mam_usage: true
    default: always
  mod_mqtt: {}
  mod_muc:
    access:
      - allow
    access_admin:
      - allow: admin
    access_create: muc_create
    access_persistent: muc_create
    access_mam:
      - allow
    default_room_options:
      mam: true
  mod_muc_admin: {}
  mod_offline:
    access_max_user_messages: max_user_offline_messages
  mod_ping: {}
  mod_privacy: {}
  mod_private: {}
  mod_proxy65:
    access: local
    max_connections: 5
  mod_pubsub:
    access_createnode: pubsub_createnode
    plugins:
      - flat
      - pep
    force_node_config:
      ## Avoid buggy clients to make their bookmarks public
      storage:bookmarks:
        access_model: whitelist
  mod_push: {}
  mod_push_keepalive: {}
  mod_register:
    ## Only accept registration requests from the "trusted"
    ## network (see access_rules section above).
    ## Think twice before enabling registration from any
    ## address. See the Jabber SPAM Manifesto for details:
    ## https://github.com/ge0rg/jabber-spam-fighting-manifesto
    ip_access: trusted_network
  mod_roster:
    versioning: true
  mod_s2s_dialback: {}
  mod_shared_roster: {}
  mod_stream_mgmt:
    resend_on_timeout: if_offline
  mod_stun_disco: {}
  mod_vcard: {}
  mod_vcard_xupdate: {}
  mod_version:
    show_os: false
```

I have two observation with messages (send_message):

- client to client ([PSI](https://psi-im.org/))
- postman to Client

In first observation I have success to exchange messages between users on psi(PSI) but when we try to send message with postman using "mod_http_api" API to the client, I am getting result `200 ok`, but Message is not being delivered. And it is not showing anywhere (logs).

Am I missing something that is important for receiving a message using ejabberd's REST API with postman?

Answer (score 0):

What a strange problem, I cannot reproduce it. You didn't show your command query, and didn't mention what exact client and configuration you are using.

Summary: Check if the command works correctly when using the ejabberdctl command line tool, and use "normal" message type, and send to bare JID, and use another client for example Gajim (just for debugging the problem).

Details:

I installed ejabberd 22.10 from source code, copied your configuration, disabled cert and tls options, started ejabberd, registered account, logged in it and executed this command:

```
$ ejabberdctl send_message headline uuu@localhost user1@localhost Restart aaa
```

The client that was logged in user1@localhost received the stanza, and displayed the headline message:

```
<message to='user1@localhost'
    from='uuu@localhost'
    type='headline'
    id='18154938236359942834'>
  <body>aaa</body>
  <subject>Restart</subject>
</message>
```

Please note: in XMPP, "headline" messages are not stored in the offline storage: they are only received by online sessions with positive priority. Maybe you are sending "headline" messages to sessions that are offline, or online with negative priority, or online with no initial presence?

It's preferable to send a "normal" message, which are stored offline:

```
ejabberdctl send_message normal uuu@localhost user1@localhost ThisisNormal bbb
```

Also, make sure your client is logged in with positive priority (this is the standard).